# Error Running Hbase Java API

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

Successfully compiled my Hbase class using

```
javac -cp "/hbase/lib/*" CreateTable.java
```

But during running it is throwing error

```
java CreateTable
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration
>           at CreateTable.main(CreateTable.java:16)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>           ... 1 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
javac -cp `hbase classpath` CreateTable.java

java -cp `hbase classpath` CreateTable
```

where `hbase classpath` is cluster classpath where cluster has installed hbase jar files
If you want to see folder location of your hbase/lib, 
you can go to hbase shell and try [image] your hbase lib jars will be displayed there.

Note : if you are using maven for your build then you have to set 'provided' as scope where you are mentioning groupid, artifactid etc...

Comment: yes I have given full folder location of hbase library. The program was compiled and class file was created but I was executing it given error that class not found

Comment: you mean run time you have given `hbase classpath` as class path to java command and still  you are not able to execute the class.. isnt it ? if thats the case can you copy paste what comand you have used. above way should work.

Comment: For compilation                                                                                          javac -cp "/opt/mapr/hbase/hbase-0.98.12/lib/*" CreateTable.java              and for execution                                                                                  java -cp "/opt/mapr/hbase/hbase-0.98.12/lib/*" CreateTable

Comment: this is the jar file hbase-clientxxxx.jar file under your lib dir  like  this ...home/hadoop/SW/hbase/lib/hbase-client-0.98.12-hadoop2.jar where the class org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration is there. can you check that?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to specifying the classpath of libraries you're depending on in order to compile your program, you need to specify them when executing your program. The dependencies aren't "compiled-in", they're just referenced during compilation to ensure that they're linked correctly, but they need to be there at runtime as well.

So, you probably want to run something like `java -cp ".;/hbase/lib/*" CreateTable` in order to have the same libraries at runtime as you used at compile time, as well as the current directory where your complied .class file is.

In enterprise programs, usually a dependency management system like Maven, or at least what's built into most IDEs, is used to help keep track of the dependencies and call Java and related tools with the right paths.

Comment: I tried that also and in that case it throwing Error which is:

Comment: Error: Could not find or load main class CreateTable

Comment: But there in CreateTable.class present

Comment: I've updated my answer; you need to include "." in the classpath to include the path where your compiled .class file is. It's been a while since I've dealt with managing classpaths manually.